# ScrollTop to next Section while hiding previous section with animation effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create srollTop effect with 3 main sections full of content. I have 3 sections where the first one is visible and the second and third are display:none. I want to achieve the effect when the first button is clicked to show the second section and hide the first section with animation and then when the second button on the second section is clicked to do the same animation effect hiding second section and showing the third one. Here is example of my code until this moment. I cannot figure out how to do it properly with animation.

```js
$(".button_1").on("click", function() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(".two").offset().top
  }, 1000);
  $(".two").css({
    "display": "block"
  });
  $(".one").css({
    "display": "none"
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.one {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.two {
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  display: none;
}

.three {
  background: purple;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  display: none;
}

.button_1,
.button_2,
.button_3 {
  border: 0;
  width: 180px;
  height: 40px;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="one">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A assumenda ipsam, rem fugit accusantium fugiat ea labore quam impedit, praesentium quisquam. Quia quam, et accusantium labore eius est accusamus perferendis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit. A assumenda ipsam, rem fugit accusantium fugiat ea labore quam impedit, praesentium quisquam. Quia quam, et accusantium labore eius est accusamus perferendis.</p>
  <button class="button_1">Click me 1</button>
</section>

<section class="two">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A assumenda ipsam, rem fugit accusantium fugiat ea labore quam impedit, praesentium quisquam. Quia quam, et accusantium labore eius est accusamus perferendis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit. A assumenda ipsam, rem fugit accusantium fugiat ea labore quam impedit, praesentium quisquam. Quia quam, et accusantium labore eius est accusamus perferendis.</p>
  <button class="button_2">Click me 2</button>
</section>

<section class="three">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A assumenda ipsam, rem fugit accusantium fugiat ea labore quam impedit, praesentium quisquam. Quia quam, et accusantium labore eius est accusamus perferendis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit. A assumenda ipsam, rem fugit accusantium fugiat ea labore quam impedit, praesentium quisquam. Quia quam, et accusantium labore eius est accusamus perferendis.</p>
  <button class="button_3">Do something else</button>
</section>
```

[Js fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxwyyj7f/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to scroll to the section only after you show it.

I've just optimized your script to work with all the section that you want.
Put the class btn on all the buttons.

```
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
  var section = $(this).closest('section');
  var next = section.next('section').show();

  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: next.offset().top
  }, 1000);
});
```

Please, have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/6y4qwLbq/1/

If you want to hide them you can use this variant:

```
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
    var section = $(this).closest('section');
  var next = section.next('section');

  section.slideUp();
  next.slideDown();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vjm95303/

All the best.

Comment: thats cool but I want to hide the previous section so once the button is clicked so if you scroll up to not be able to see the first section @DanieleDeMatteo

Comment: Hi @PeterSolvien, you're right. I've added a new script. Let me know.

Comment: That's very cool, but is there any way to add some delay(animation) during the changing ? Im talking for the second variant that you provided to me. ( Showing the next section with let's say 1 second or 2 second of smooth animation delay ) ?

Comment: Sure, you can use this:
section.slideUp(function() {
   next.slideDown();
  });

Now you are waiting the first animation to start the second one. You can also put a setTimeout to extend the delay.